# How to secure webHttpBinding?

Tags: json, wcf, ssl, web-config

In my WCF service I am trying to to send data to the client using JSON over an SSL connection. I was able to secure the OData database source to my client using `wsHttpBinding` with a security mode of `Transport`. Why is `webHttpBinding` not able to do the same in order to use SSL? How would I configure an endpoint that needs to use JSON to use an SSL connection as well?

Essentially what is the difference between `webHttpBinding` and `wsHttpBinding`?

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TransportSecurity">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="EndpBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="DataService4.DataService">

    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="DataService4.IService" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior" />

    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpsBinding" address="mex" />   
  </service>
</services>

<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this article will solve your problem.
[Creating a WCF RESTful Service And Secure It Using HTTPS Over SSL](http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.com/2012/05/creating-wcf-restful-service-and-secure.html)

Comment: The link is broken. This is why link only answers should not be considered as an answer.

Comment: The link is not broken, there was some problem with my browser which displayed 404 not found page. Anyway I think it's best to include a summary of the article in the answer as it says in SO's how to answer page `Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.`. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

The relevant part from http://www.allenconway.net/2012/05/creating-wcf-restful-service-and-secure.html is this:

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding>
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

but also remove exposing metadata if desired.

the details are documented in msdn here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924478(v=vs.110).aspx

the relevant parts are:

> Transport   Security is provided using HTTPS. The service needs to be
>   configured with SSL certificates. The message is entirely secured
>   using HTTPS and the service is authenticated by the client using the
>   service’s SSL certificate. The client authentication is controlled
>   through the ClientCredentialType attribute of the [transport of
>    webHttpBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924526(v=vs.110).aspx).